# ZSH glob expansion without menu

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to configure zshell in such a way that:

```
$ ls *<TAB>
# results in
ls a b c d e f g <cursor>
```

where "a, b, .., g" are the files that match the wildcard.
Instead it gives me the default completion menu.

I do however want the completion menu if there is no glob to expand.
So

```
$ ls * | <tab>
```

would give me the command completion menu.

I've seen this working. But I do not really no how to configure globbing in zshell.
Anyone?

Comment: This is the default behavior with zsh 4.3.17 (both with the recommended and an empty *.zshrc*). Could you post the output of `zstyle`?

Comment: Ah thank you. The one zshrc available online that I had not yet seen: the official example... I'll post an answer based on what I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by Dennis, I looked up the recommended default, which can be found here: [offical default zshrc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Contrib/startup/std/zshrc)

I used their completion settings, and adapted them from there, so I can't tell for sure what did the trick.
But I'm presuming this line was key:

```
# insert all expansions for expand completer
zstyle ':completion:*:expand:*' tag-order all-expansions
```

Comment: Thank you! It’s weird that `compinstall` doesn’t seem to include this setting.